# Change default audio track in mp4 video

Tags: audio

I often download mp4 videos with multiple audio tracks. 
Is it any way or some tools with explanation to change default audio track ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -disposition:a:0 0 -disposition:a:1 default output.mp4
```

Audio tracks (streams) are numbered from `0`.

Supposing the input video has 2 audio streams, and the default audio stream is `0`, we need to

- *remove* the “default” disposition from it (by setting it to 0: `-disposition:a:0 0`) and
- *set it* to the audio stream `1` (by setting it to “default”: `-disposition:a:1 default`).

In general, *remove* the “default” disposition from all audio streams except one, and *set it* for it.

---

*Note:*

Not all media players honor default audio stream — for example Media Player Classic don't honor it (but you may set the preference by the language of audio streams), while VLC Media Player and FFplay do.

---

*Proof (note the location of the “(default)” tag):*

```
ffprobe -hide_banner input.mp4
```

gives (among others)

```
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 74 kb/s
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

while

```
ffprobe -hide_banner output.mp4
```

gives

```
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 74 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

The numbering here numbers *all* tracks, so `#0:0` (omitted from the FFprobe outputs) is the first (video) track, and `#0:1` and `#0:2` are audio tracks.

Comment: I tried it with different variants (from 1 to 4) but it does't work for me. Unfortunately. Default audio track stays the same.

Comment: I edited my answer — you also need to remove the “default” disposition from all other audio tracks.

Comment: Note that not all media players honor the “default” disposition — some of them simply start playing the first audio stream.

Comment: Thank you so much! I use VLC player. And the edited answer helped me!

Comment: combining this (changing default) and MarianD's answer (changing order) works great...now it'll probably work on any player

Answer (score 2):

Some media players simply start playing the first audio stream (track). For them you may simply change the order of audio streams.

For example, suppose you have 1 video stream and 3 audio streams in your input file, and you want to move the 3rd audio stream to be the first of audio streams.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -map 0:a:2 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -c copy output.mp4
```

so `-map 0:a:2` places the 3rd audio stream (stream numbers begin with `0`, so `2` is the 3rd one) in front of all others audio streams (`-map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1`).

---

*Note:*

- `0:v` means *all* **v**ideo streams in the input file `0` (input files are numbered from `0`)
- `0:a:2` means: input file `0`, **a**udio stream number `2`
- `0:a:0` means: input file `0`, **a**udio stream number `0`
- `0:a:1` means: input file `0`, **a**udio stream number `1`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution in Avidemux. (prveious answers are not always working)

1. Open video in Avidemux
2. In "Audio -> Select track" choose only one track you need
3. In "output format" select "mp4 muxer"
4. Save the file using "File -> Save as"

There is also a disadvantage in this method. It removes all other tracks but it's good enough for some cases.